# Using a resolution larger than my monitor isn't working

Tags: windows-10, resolution, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell P2418HT 24 inch touchscreen 1080p 60Hz monitor overclocked to 76Hz and a GTX 1070 Ti. I want to use 1440p on my monitor.

I know how to set up a custom resolution, and I did that. I open NVIDIA Control Panel, but when I press Apply after selecting the custom resolution, (2560x1440) nothing happens and it disappears from the resolution selector. I press *Customize...*, then check the box next to *Enable custom resolutions not exposed by this display*, then hit Apply again. Nothing happens and the custom resolution disappears.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does rebooting your PC after you enable supersampling make any difference?

Comment: What's Supersampling?

Comment: That's the technical term for when you run a game at a higher resolution than your monitor can support. https://www.howtogeek.com/316682/how-to-run-pc-games-at-resolutions-higher-than-your-monitor-with-supersampling/

Comment: I'm not using it for games, it's just for productivity

Comment: Oh I see. What happens if you reboot after you enable that setting in the NVIDIA Control Panel?

Comment: I shall try that now

Comment: Now the option doesn't disappear, but It doesn't do anything

Comment: Are your NVIDIA drivers completely up to date?

Comment: Updated them yesterday

Comment: I'm almost out of ideas. Are you using an HDMI cable by any chance?

Comment: Nope. DisplayPort. Not sure about the version